# Fatal Error in PHP When Updating Record: Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: php, html, css, web, phpmyadmin

I'm encountering a critical issue while attempting to update a record in my PHP application that interacts with a MySQL database. Whenever I try to execute the update statement, I receive the following error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bd_pastelera`.`producto`, CONSTRAINT `producto_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_CATEGORIA`) REFERENCES `categoria_producto` (`ID_CATEGORIA`)) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pasteleria-Dolce-Rivoluzione\Formulario\editar.php:141 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Pasteleria-Dolce-Rivoluzione\Formulario\editar.php(141): mysqli_stmt->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pasteleria-Dolce-Rivoluzione\Formulario\editar.php on line 141
**

This error appears to be related to a foreign key constraint (producto_ibfk_2) that references the ID_CATEGORIA column in the categoria_producto table. However, I'm struggling to identify the root cause of this issue and how to resolve it.

Heres my code:

```
<body>
  <?php
  $imagenExistente = "";
  include ("../config/conexion.php");

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $idProducto = $_POST["idProducto"];
    $nombreP = $_POST["nombreP"];
    $descripcionP = $_POST["descripcionP"];
    $precioP = $_POST["precioP"];
    $stockP = $_POST["stockP"];
    $categoriaP = $_POST["categoriaP"];
    $medidaP = $_POST["medidaP"];
    $adminP = $_POST["adminP"];

    /*
    // Imprimir el valor de $categoriaP para verificarlo
    echo $categoriaP;
    echo $idProducto;
    echo $nombreP;
    echo $descripcionP;
    echo $precioP;
    echo $stockP;
    echo $medidaP;
    echo $adminP;
    */

    // Manejo de la imagen
    if (!empty($_FILES["imagenP"]["tmp_name"])) {
      $imagenP = $_FILES["imagenP"]["tmp_name"];
      $imagenData = file_get_contents($imagenP);
    } else {
      $imagenData = $imagenExistente;
    }

    // Realizar la actualización en la base de datos
    $sql = "UPDATE producto SET N_PRODUCTO=?, DESCRIPCION=?, PRECIO=?, STOCK=?, ID_CATEGORIA=?, IMG=?, MEDIDA=?, ID_ADMIN=? WHERE ID_PRODUCTO=?";
    $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssdibisii", $nombreP, $descripcionP, $precioP, $stockP, $categoriaP, $imagenData, $medidaP, $adminP, $idProducto);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      echo "Producto actualizado correctamente.";
    } else {
      echo "Error al actualizar el producto: " . $stmt->error;
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conexion->close();
  } else {
    $idProducto = $_GET["id"];
    $sql = "SELECT p.N_PRODUCTO, p.DESCRIPCION, p.PRECIO, p.STOCK, p.ID_CATEGORIA, p.IMG, c.N_CATEGORIA, p.MEDIDA, a.NOMBRE AS NOMBRE_ADMIN, p.ID_ADMIN 
            FROM producto p
            INNER JOIN categoria_producto c ON p.ID_CATEGORIA = c.ID_CATEGORIA
            INNER JOIN admin a ON p.ID_ADMIN = a.ID_ADMIN
            WHERE p.ID_PRODUCTO = ?";
    $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $idProducto);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      $stmt->bind_result($nombreP, $descripcionP, $precioP, $stockP, $categoriaP, $imagenData, $categoriaDescripcion, $medidaP, $adminNombre, $adminP);
      $stmt->fetch();
      $stmt->close();
    }
  }
  ?>

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Editar Producto</h1>
    <form action="editar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="idProducto" value="<?php echo $idProducto; ?>">

      <label for="nombreP">Nombre Producto</label>
      <input type="text" id="nombreP" name="nombreP" value="<?php echo $nombreP; ?>">

      <label for="descripcionP">Descripción</label>
      <textarea id="descripcionP" name="descripcionP"><?php echo $descripcionP; ?></textarea>

      <label for="precioP">Precio</label>
      <input type="text" id="precioP" name="precioP" value="<?php echo $precioP; ?>">

      <label for="stockP">Stock</label>
      <input type="text" id="stockP" name="stockP" value="<?php echo $stockP; ?>">

      <label for="categoriaP">Categoría</label>
      <select id="categoriaP" name="categoriaP">
        <?php
        // Obtener todas las categorías de la base de datos
        $sqlCategorias = "SELECT ID_CATEGORIA, N_CATEGORIA FROM categoria_producto";
        $resultCategoria = $conexion->query($sqlCategorias);
        while ($rowCategoria = $resultCategoria->fetch_assoc()) {
          $categoriaID = $rowCategoria["ID_CATEGORIA"];
          $categoriaDescripcion = $rowCategoria["N_CATEGORIA"];
          $selectedCategoria = ($categoriaID == $categoriaP) ? "selected" : "";
          echo "<option value='$categoriaID' $selectedCategoria>$categoriaDescripcion</option>";
        }
        ?>
      </select>

      <label for="medidaP">Medida</label>
      <input type="text" id="medidaP" name="medidaP" value="<?php echo $medidaP; ?>">

      <label for="adminP">Admin</label>
      <select id="adminP" name="adminP">
        <?php
        // Obtener todos los administradores de la base de datos
        $sqlAdmins = "SELECT ID_ADMIN, NOMBRE FROM admin";
        $resultAdmins = $conexion->query($sqlAdmins);
        while ($rowAdmin = $resultAdmins->fetch_assoc()) {
          $adminID = $rowAdmin["ID_ADMIN"];
          $adminNombre = $rowAdmin["NOMBRE"];
          $selectedAdmin = ($adminID == $adminP) ? "selected" : "";
          echo "<option value='$adminID' $selectedAdmin>$adminNombre</option>";
        }
        ?>
      </select>

      <label for="imagenP">Imagen (JPG, JPEG o PNG)</label>
      <?php if (!empty($imagenData)): ?>
        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($imagenData); ?>" alt="Imagen" class="img-preview">
      <?php endif; ?>
      <input type="file" id="imagenP" name="imagenP">

      <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

What I've Tried:

Ensured that the ID_CATEGORIA value I'm trying to update in the producto table exists in the categoria_producto table.
Checked for any database integrity issues, but couldn't find any discrepancies.

Request for Assistance:

I'm seeking guidance on how to diagnose and resolve this foreign key constraint error. What could be causing this issue, and what steps can I take to successfully update the product record without encountering this error?

Any help or insights into resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the value of this variable `$categoriaP`?

Comment: $categoriaP can be numbers from 1 to 5 (id), depending on the category you select in the combo box it should store the number related to that category